# Why does np.savetxt return an empty file if I hand it in a large dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

My actual `sensor_data` is much larger than the array below, and the `x_train.txt` file I get is empty.

```
def convert_gesture_lists_to_files(i):
    sensor_data = ([[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]])
    x_train = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(sensor_data)):
        for j in range(len(sensor_data[i])):
            for k in range(len(sensor_data[i][j])):
                np.append(x_train, sensor_data[i][j][k])
    np.savetxt("x_train", x_train)
```

When I print `sensor_data[0][0][0]` I get `(1, 2, 3)`. Is this problem happening because the data is too large?

Also, my `sensor_data` is a regular Python list, and I don't know how to get the shape of it; otherwise, I would share that.

Comment: How big is that file, is the file size changing on disk after execution is done?

Comment: It's zero bytes.

Comment: Arrays *are not lists*. Lists are *not arrays*. `np.append(x_train, sensor_data[i][j][k])` **returns a new array**, which you immediately discard. Your loop doesn't accomplish anything. Try `x_train = np.append(x_train, ...)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that worked. Thanks

Comment: Also, this loop is totally pointless. Just do `x_train = np.array(sensor_data).flatten()`

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Note, you should *never be doing this*. Using `np.append` in this way is a quadratic-time algorithm. Almost certainly, you can do better, like what I did above, which is linear time.

Comment: When I try the second I get an error saying `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

Comment: Too many unnecessary loops here.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 then `sensor_data` doesn't look like you said it does. Likely, it isn't "rectangular" shaped, rather, it is staggered. Probably, you can just do something like `np.array([x for sub in sensor_data for ssub in sub for x in ssub])`

Comment: Before you do the `savetxt`, print `x_train.shape` and `x_train.dtype`.  You need to understand, really know, what you are trying to save.  Don't assume it is big or anything else.  Verify!

Comment: The shape returns `(137802,)` and the dtype returns `float64`